# Creating the dynamic style tag with the incrementing ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

***About the Code***

I have a code that increment the ID on each click but the problem is in css. I have a style implemented in the #dummy ID so when I click first time the style display as I have written in the css but on second, third, fourth and so on clicks it does not appear. The reason is the incrementing ID

***What I want:***

I want, also to create a new style tag with a new incremented ID on each click after each element and implement all the styles present in the #dummy ID.

**For example :**

On second click

The id will incremented as it should be that is id="dummy--1"

Under that a style tag should be some thing like this :

```
<style>
    #dummy--1 {
      background-color: bisque;
    }
    #dummy--1 H1 {
      color: blue;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    #dummy--1 p {
      color: green;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
</style>
```

How can I achieve it.

[Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/fhL9473e/1/). Please check the elements or console to see incrementing id's

UPDATED:

Sorry guys but I do not want to use div[id^="dummy"]. I just want to create a new style tag as I have mentioned above

Comment: infinite automatic style generator based on a ID? oO

Comment: @F.bernal Yes Please help me

Comment: the style should be the same for all dummy divs, right?

Comment: @mikepa88 I think no, that's problem, he wants infinite style generator oO

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934720/how-to-increment-decrement-hex-color-values-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: @F.bernal You are right. I need something like  that

Comment: @user7791702 what's the criteria for the styles applied to the new divs ? random colors and sizes?

Comment: @user7791702 were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @StanislavKvitash it helps me.

Comment: @user7791702 so probably can you accept one of the answers?

Comment: @StanislavKvitash Thanks for remembering me I have forgotten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice you to use some other approach (using css like other people recommend here), but if you really want to try generate the styles manually then you can generate styles string (in the example using [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and placeholders) and then [append it to](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) `head` tag:

```js
$array = {
  "sections": {
    "H": {
      "name": "dummy",
      "html": "<div id=\"dummy\"><h1>Some Title</h1><p>This is a para</p></div>"
    }
  }
}

var defaultStyle = "#dummy--{id} {background-color: bisque;}#dummy--{id} H1 {color: {h1-color};font-size: 20px;}#dummy--{id} p{color: green;font-size: 15px;}"

$(function() {
  // counter which holds the counts of click
  var count = -1;
  $('#cm').click(function(event) {
    $htmlData = $array["sections"]["H"]['html'];
    // check the count value for second click
    if (++count > 0)
      // in case of not a first click parse the html and generate a jQuery object
      $htmlData = $($htmlData).attr('id', function(i, v) {
        // update the attrubute value
        return v + '--' + count
        // get back the html content from the DOM object
      })[0].outerHTML
    //$('#content').html($htmlData);
    $($htmlData).appendTo('#content').hide().slideDown();
    
    var generated = defaultStyle.replace(/{id}/gi, count).replace(/{h1-color}/gi, count % 2 ? "red":"yellow");
    $("<style type='text/css'>" + generated + "</style>").appendTo("head");
  });
})
```

```css
#dummy {
  background-color: bisque;
}
#dummy H1 {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#dummy p {
  color: green;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="cm">Click me</button>

<ul id="content">
  
</ul>
```

Hope this idea will help you.

**UPDATE:** You can also try to manage your style using [jQuery `css()` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Answer (score 2):

Make use of styling based on attribute filtering in your CSS. Each `id` starting with "dummy" will be selected.

```css
div[id^="dummy"] {
  background-color: bisque;
}

div[id^="dummy"] h1 {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 20px;
}

div[id^="dummy"] p {
  color: green;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dummy--1">
  <h1>test</h1>
</div>
<div id="dummy--2">
  <p>test</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`div[id^="dummy"]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) will Select every  element whose `ID` begins with `dummy`

```
div[id^="dummy"]{
  background-color: bisque;
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fhL9473e/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

Give them a class

```
<div id="dummy--x" class="dummy"><h1>Some Title</h1><p>This is a para</p></div>
```

And apply css to that class

```
.dummy {  background-color: bisque; } ... etc
```

The other answers with the id selector will work, but that's what classes are for, not ids

Comment: I fully agree with you. However, when giving a response like you did I was told several times I had not answered the question. Hence the answer I gave. :)

Comment: yeah, but if this person does not fully understand the concept of css targeting ids and classes, it's better that he knows how to achieve it properly than use weird css selectors for no reason.