# Is there a way to automatically change the shade of background color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Was wondering if there was a way to use a spectrum to change the background color based off of variables such as temp the higher it is, the more the colour will become orange from blue? or would I actually have to assign values

```
if (temp < 10) {
document.body.className = "background-cold";
} else if (temp > 10) {
document.body.className = "background-warm";
}
```

```
.background-cold {
  background: linear-gradient(
    179.31deg,
    rgba(48, 87, 89, 0.97) 9.28%,
    #fdfeff 167.45%
  );
}

.background-warm {
  background: linear-gradient(
    179.31deg,
    rgba(204, 101, 26, 0.97) 9.28%,
    #fdfeff 167.45%
  );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Of course there's a way. What _specific_ question do you have about your attempt?

Comment: Something like https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-create-better-themes-with-css-variables-5a3744105c74/

Comment: I want to be able change color automatically rather than ahving to assign the values for each color i want? If that makes sense

Comment: Well, I guess the first thing you'd need to do is get the temperature... Then you'd need to decide what values you want to change based on the temperature (you may want to use something other than RGBA, like HSL or something that lends itself to this kind of manipulation). Then you write code to change the values based on the temperature received. If you have a question with one of those specific steps, then you should as a specific question about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var hue = temp * someScale; // use some formula to determine the appropriate hue from the temperature
var saturation = 1;
var lightness = 1;
document.body.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(179.31deg, hsla(${hue}%,${saturation}%,${lightness}%) 9.28%, #fdfeff 167.45%)`;
```

Comment: For some reason "document.body.style.backgroundImage"d esont work for which is why ive been doing "document.body.className" and referencing it inside the CSS, is there another way around this?

Comment: Maybe `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundImage = ...` ?

Comment: Ive fixex the problem, using "document.body.style.backgroundColor" worked and there was a problem with the input but all i had to do was add a "%" after each {hue} {saturation} and {lightness} becasue they took it as percentages.

Comment: good catch. my fault on the syntax. was writing from a phone. i'll update the answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

For the approach you intend to do I don't recomemend using the `.className` attribution. It will be hardcoded and that's not what you want. You can just use `style.setProperty(string, string)` in wich the first parameter is the **CSS atttribute** and the second parameter is the **CSS value**. Both of them need to be strings in order to work.

```
let colorValue = 'linear-gradient(VALUES)';
document.body.style.setProperty('background', colorValue);
```

By using the previous code you can now set directly the background you want. However your still need a function to create a dynamic **colorValue** according to the **temperature**. This can become a little complex depending on the color values you intend to apply. A possible solution for this can be found in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12934900/11860800.